# How to add Single connection to Multiple DB's on the same oracle server in DBeaver?

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I have many Databases on the same Oracle server and I am using Dbeaver as an IDE to connect to the databases. However I need to create connection for each database separately even though they are on the same server. Is there anyway we can create single connection and switch to the required DB just like we have it in SQL server ?

I tried to connect the multiple DB's on the same oracle server using DBeaver and I am not able to do So

Comment: Please make sure you are using the correct terminology as [Oracle and SQL Server have different meanings for a "database"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130441/instance-and-database-oracle-vs-sql-server).

Comment: See also: [Difference between database vs user vs schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37012/118722)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL*Plus supports the [`CONNECT` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/CONNECT.html#GUID-47249D66-7ED9-48BE-9C79-CE250ABB88B8):

```sql
connect username@connect_identifier
```

If DBeaver supports that SQL*Plus command then you should be able to use it in a script to change the connection from one user to another user (or from one database instance to another database instance if you specify the `connect_identifier`).

Alternatively:

1. Run the script which needs to connect to multiple users/databases in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) rather than DBeaver; or
2. Connect to a user that has appropriate privileges to access all the users within the database instance that you need to access and ensure that your script prefixes all table identifiers with the user's schema identifier.

   I.e. change:

   ```sql
   CONNECT user1

   SELECT * FROM table1;

   CONNECT user2

   SELECT * FROM table2;
   ```

   to:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM user1.table1;

   SELECT * FROM user2.table2;
   ```

   And connect to a user than has been granted `SELECT` permissions to both `user1.table1` and `user2.table2`.

Comment: Here the question is not about the different users. It is about Different Databases on the same oracle server.

Comment: @RamakrishnaKurudagi Oracle and SQL Server use different terminology. In Oracle, there is only [one database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130441/instance-and-database-oracle-vs-sql-server) (unless RAC) which typically has a single instance (but may have more), an instance may have multiple tablespaces and users own the tablespaces and each user has a schema of the same name. Each user owns the objects (tables, etc.) in their own schema. Regardless of the differences in terminology, if you can use `CONNECT` then you can connect to different users or to different databases/servers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

Although these databases reside on the same database server (so host is the same), they have different *description* (port, service name). Moreover, when you establish connection to any user in any database, you're required to use appropriate credentials (username, password) and provide target database.

All that means that one connection to one user in any database requires separate connection.

---

As of the way of access to different users' data:

- if that "another user" is in the **same database**, it (that user) should grant some privileges to you (`grant select` is the most common), and then you can either precede table's name with owner name , e.g.

  ```
  select * from another_user.employees;
  ```

  or create synonym in your schema which points to other user's object(s).
- if that "another user" is in **another database**, then you'll need a **database link** to access those tables.

Comment: My question is about connecting multiple databases hosted on the same server with same user name. Instead of creating connection to each database, is there ant way we can connect with single connection and just switch the database whenever required. We have this capability for SQL server connections.

Comment: As I said, **no** (as far as I can tell). It doesn't matter that **username** is the same - you're connecting to a different database (different port, different service name). You'll need a new connection.